# Event handling in Java (JTree + JButton)

Tags: java, swing, events, jbutton, jtree

```
private void createEvents() 
{
    menuFileExit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    ////// Events on tree selection
    jtStoryViewer.addTreeSelectionListener(new TreeSelectionListener() 
    {
        public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent arg0) 
        {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode selection = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) jtStoryViewer.getLastSelectedPathComponent();
            Object nodeObject = selection.getUserObject();



            ////// Checks if selected node is a String (only story title is a string)
            if(selection.getUserObject().getClass().getName() == "java.lang.String" )
            {
                tfTitle.setText(nodeObject.toString());


                ////// Action listener for Change Button
                btnChange.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
                {
                    ////// Title text swap
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
                    {
                        selection.setUserObject(tfTitle.getText());
                        ((DefaultTreeModel)jtStoryViewer.getModel()).nodeChanged(selection);
                    }
                });
            }
            ///// checks if the object is a chapter object
            if(selection.getUserObject().getClass().getName() == "ISW.common.Chapter")
            {
                Chapter chapter = (Chapter) selection.getUserObject();
                tfTitle.setText(chapter.toString());



                ////// Action listener for Change Button
                btnChange.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
                {
                    ////// Title text swap
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
                    {
                        chapter.setTitle(tfTitle.getText());
                        ((DefaultTreeModel)jtStoryViewer.getModel()).nodeChanged(selection);

                    }
                });
            }


        }
    }); 
}
```

[image: visualization of the problem]

I am using `JTree` to display and modify some objects. I added a `TreeSelectionListener` to get the object data on selection. For now I want to be able to change the title of an object, it works fine on first selection on the tree , I change the value in the text box and the "Change" button works just fine, but when I move on to next objects, the change button also modifies the value of all previously selected objects.

I guess it is caused due to my improper usage of the ActionListeners but I can't tell for sure and at this point I'm stuck.

Will be grateful for any hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't keep adding an `ActionListener` to the `btnChange` `JButton` within the `TreeSelectionListener#valueChanged` method.

This will cause the button to call EVERY `ActionListener` you have previously

Instead, give the `btnChange` a single `ActionListener`, when clicked, can act on the currently selected node (by checking the `JTree` it self).  You could have the `TreeSelectionListener#valueChanged` method enable or disable the `btnChange` based on the validity of the selection

Also, `if(selection.getUserObject().getClass().getName() == "ISW.common.Chapter")` isn't how `String` comparison is done in Java, instead you should use something more like `if("ISW.common.Chapter".equals(selection.getUserObject().getClass().getName()))`

Comment: Thank you, I decalred a single action listener and made the button act according to current selection in the tree and it works now, also fixed the string comparisons. Im a beginner to java and your tips helped me much.

Comment: Glad it could help ;)